# Medallion structure in MS Fabric

Tags: delta-lake, microsoft-fabric

I have to implement a delta lake using MS fabric and I don't know how to implement the medallion structure in this new tool, any ideas or help?

[This is the official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-engineering/tutorial-lakehouse-introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very high level, with little detail.

However with MS-Fabric, in the workspace you can create three Lakehouses, Bronze, Sliver and Gold, then use the in the (for example) the Silver layer note books a reference to Bronze.Sometable, to get data from that layer into the Sliver layer, then Sliver.someothertable into the Gold layer. You can use the Spark instance, or SQL Endpoint in this way.